# Interpolate missing values in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have some intraday stock data saved into a MySQL table which looks like this:

```
+----------+-------+
| tick     | quote |
+----------+-------+
| 08:00:10 |  5778 |
| 08:00:11 |  5776 |
| 08:00:12 |  5778 |
| 08:00:13 |  5778 |
| 08:00:14 |  NULL |
| 08:00:15 |  NULL |
| 08:00:16 |  5779 |
| 08:00:17 |  5778 |
| 08:00:18 |  5780 |
| 08:00:19 |  NULL |
| 08:00:20 |  5781 |
| 08:00:21 |  5779 |
| 08:00:22 |  5779 |
| 08:00:23 |  5779 |
| 08:00:24 |  5778 |
| 08:00:25 |  5779 |
| 08:00:26 |  5777 |
| 08:00:27 |  NULL |
| 08:00:28 |  NULL |
| 08:00:29 |  5776 |
+----------+-------+
```

As you can see, there are some points where no data is available (quote is `NULL`). What I would like to do is a simple step interpolation. This means each `NULL` value should be updated with the last value available. The only way I managed to do this is with cursors, which is pretty slow due to the large amount of data. I'm basically searching something like this:

```
UPDATE table AS t1
SET quote = (SELECT quote FROM table AS t2 
             WHERE t2.tick < t1.tick AND 
                   t2.quote IS NOT NULL 
             ORDER BY t2.tick DESC 
             LIMIT 1)
WHERE quote IS NULL
```

Of course this query will not work, but this is how it should look like.

I would appreciate any ideas on how this can be solved without cursors and temp tables.

Comment: Haven't looked at this closely but why doesn't that query work? If it is just because you get the error about `You can't specify target table ... for update in FROM clause` the workaround for that [is here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/)

Comment: @Martin Smith It's not so easy here. In subquery you have reference to main query `t2.tick < t1.tick` so you can't easily wrap it in a another subquery.

Comment: @Kamil - Ah right I see. Is there any way of using user variables in an update statement in MySQL similar to the `row_number` simulation technique?

Comment: Yes I have already tried that workaround, but as Kamil said, that reference will not work, because t1 is not visible in the nested subquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```sql
SET @prev = NULL;

UPDATE   ticks
SET      quote= @prev := coalesce(quote, @prev)
ORDER BY tick;
```

BTW the same trick works for reading:

```sql
SELECT   t.tick, @prev := coalesce(t.quote, @prev)
FROM     ticks t
JOIN     (SELECT @prev:=NULL) as x -- initializes @prev
ORDER BY tick
```

Comment: +1 Did wonder in the comments if something like this was possible.

Comment: @arnaud +1 for that, but you are not interpolating, you are repeating the previous value, You need to update with average(@prev,@next)!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is reference to main query in subquery `t2.tick < t1.tick`. Because of this you can't simply wrap the subquery in a another subquery.

If this is one time query and there is not so many data, you can do something like that:

```
UPDATE `table` AS t1
SET quote = (SELECT quote FROM (SELECT quote, tick FROM `table` AS t2 WHERE t2.quote IS NOT NULL) as t3 WHERE t3.tick < t1.tick ORDER BY t3.tick DESC LIMIT 1)
WHERE quote IS NULL
```

But really, really don't use that as it will be probably to slow. On each null quote, this query selects all data from table `table` and then from results it gets desired row.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a (temporary) table with the same layout as your table and run the following two queries:

**Insert all interpolations into the temp_stock table**

```
INSERT INTO temp_stock (tick, quote) 
  SELECT s2.tick
         , (s1.quote + s3.quote) /2 as quote
  FROM stock 
  INNER JOIN stock s1 ON (s1.tick < s2.tick) 
  INNER JOIN stock s3 ON (s3.tick > s2.tick) 
  WHERE s2.quote IS NULL
  GROUP BY s2.tick
  HAVING s1.tick = MAX(s1.tick), s3.tick = MIN(s3.tick)
```

**Update the stock table with the temp values**

```
  UPDATE stock s 
  INNER JOIN temp_stock ts ON (ts.tick = s.tick) SET s.quote = ts.quote
```

It does use a temp table (make sure it's a memory table for speed), but it doesn't need a cursor.