# Autoincrement manually a column MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns:

```
[id,name,public_id]
```

actually the table contains

```
[1,john,0]
[2,sara,0]
[3,jack,0]
.....
```

I want to change the third column to 1050,1051,1052....

```
[1,john,1050]
[2,sara,1051]
[3,jack,1052]
.....
```

How can I make that update?

Some considerations: The public id must be over 1049 and must be consecutive. For example for 100 rows the public_id must be [1050....1149]

Thanks in advance

Comment: For MySQL you could probably increment a user variable similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299400/interpolate-missing-values-in-a-mysql-table/7299650#7299650)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table's name is TEST_TABLE, this MySQL syntax will update PUBLIC_ID with consecutive values starting from 1500 (and in order of ID):

```
REPLACE INTO TEST_TABLE
SELECT TEST_TABLE.ID, TEST_TABLE.NAME, @ROWNUM := @ROWNUM + 1
FROM
    TEST_TABLE,
    (SELECT @rownum := 1499) R
ORDER BY ID
```

In plain English:

- For each row, figure out its order when data is sorted by ID. Call this order "ROWNUM".
- Put ROWNUM (+ starting offset) back to the table instead of the original PUBLIC_ID.

WARNING: According to [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html), REPLACE will actually delete a duplicated row before inserting it again (instead of just updating modified fields), which my be an issue in the presence of foreign keys.

(*Not sure about SQLite, but I'm guessing you could employ a similar general idea.*)

Answer (score 5):

You can do an update like this:

```
UPDATE table SET public_id = id + 1049
```

With this, you are using the ID, and adding 1049 to it to get the result you need

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer but the id field is not consecutive =(

Comment: It is consecutive in your example. Is it just a bad example?